# iOS: AVCaptureSession no audio when maxDuration met

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avkit, avcapturemoviefileoutput

today I have an issue with the AVCaptureSession.

My issue is that when I set the MaxRecordedDuration to let's say 23 seconds, if the 23 seconds is reached and the recorder is still recording then it will stop with an error. I have no issue with what occurs during the process, but the video after reaching the max recorded duration doesn't contain any audio! This is how I set my maxDuration:

```
let maxDurationSeconds: Float64 = self.remainingVideoDuration
let maxDurationPreferredTimeScale: Int32 = 600
let maxRecordedDuration = CMTime(seconds: maxDurationSeconds, preferredTimescale: maxDurationPreferredTimeScale)
FakeMovieOutput.maxRecordedDuration = maxRecordedDuration
```

The Fileoutput error code I get is "-11810" and the message is "Recording Stopped", and although I get an error I also receive the outputFileURL.

One thing to consider before attempting to help, The audio is only missing if the max duration is met.